# Gradle equivalent of Maven Enforcer's RequireReleaseDeps

Tags: maven, gradle, snapshot, maven-enforcer-plugin

What would the Gradle equivalent of using the Maven Enforcer Plugin to prevent releases from pointing to snapshot dependencies be? Is this possible at all?

I would like to be able to prevent a release from happening if there's any snapshot dependency on the build. I know I could probably code my way through it but I was wondering if there was any "standard" or obvious way of doing it with gradle and I couldn't find anything on the web about it.

**SOLUTION**

Used resolution strategy as suggested by correct answer:

```
project.getConfigurations().all { config ->
    config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        //verifying that versions do not contain "SNAPSHOT"
        if (details.requested.version.contains("SNAPSHOT")) {
            throw new GradleException(sprintf("Using snapshot version of %s.%s", 
                [details.requested.group, details.requested.name]))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own resolution strategy that will reject SNAPSHOT dependencies. Take a look at https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:dependency_resolution to see how this works and what are your possibilities.

Comment: I actually never thanked you for this, but using your pointer I was able to implement the solution :)